# How to upload multiple images in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

I have tried this code to implement multiple images in iOS. Didn't work as I wanted:

```
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

// string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"fileToUpload[]";



NSArray *arrayfile=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:FileParamConstant,FileParamConstant ,nil];
// the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jackson.amtpl.in/tranzop/api/customertest/postorder"];

// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
for (int i=0; i<upload_img_array.count; i++) {
   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:[upload_img_array objectAtIndex:0]],1);    // add image data
// NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([upload_img_array objectAtIndex:i], 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image%d.png\"\r\n", FileParamConstant,i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
//img_send     is a UIImage with u want to send
     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img_send);





                         str_img= [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];









                NSDictionary *post_dir = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



                [post_dir setValue:str_img forKey:@"image_string"];



                NSData *jsData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:post_dir options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];



                NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

                self.receivedData = data;





                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL STRING"];



                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];



                //set http method

                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

                [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

                [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

                [request setHTTPBody:jsData];



                //initialize a connection from request

                NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

                self.connection=connection;





                //start the connection

                [connection start];



                NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

                NSError *error = nil;





                NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

                NSLog(@"~~~~~ Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);

            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
-(void)uploadImages{
    // image.finalImage - is image itself
    // totalCount - Total number of images need to upload on server

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"Key":@"Value",@"Key":@"Value"};
    [manager POST:serverURL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.finalImage) name:@"ImageName" fileName:[[Helper getRandomString:8] stringByAppendingString:@".png"] mimeType:@"image/png"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        _uploadCounter+=1;
        if(_uploadCounter<totalCount){
            [self uploadImages];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Uploading all images done");
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }];
}
```

This tutorial will help you:
https://charangiri.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/how-to-upload-multiple-image-to-server/